# How to have a view travel the path of an inverted parabola?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-graphics, core-animation

I have an inverted parabola and i need to have a view traverse through the path of the parabola.The view should slightly rotate and translate along the path of the parabola.

I did some research and found that BezierPath (quadcurve with control points) could be used to lay the path of the parabola out and then we could use CAKeyFramAnimation to move the object along the path.Animating the view object along the path of the parabola is whats confusing me.
How do i keep changing the starting points of the object within the parabola and retain the latest state of the view

Here's a brief description of what i want to achieve with the view in the parabola

The view starts from a particular point in the parabola and then traverses the parabola till the specified end point.
**How do i find out the end point within the parabola?** 
Once the view reaches its end point.For the next traversal it can start from that point and then move on to any other point within the parabola.This happens continuously based on the next end point.

This is a rough sketch oh how the path and the view would look like

[image]

And also i would like both the rotation and translation of the view traversing the path to happen simultaneously

How can this be done?

Thank you!

Comment: You already know `CAKeyFramAnimation`, please try it out. Mathematics is the answer to the other part about how you know a particular point on the path.

Comment: @Wain Can i specify the start and end points of the view in CAKeyFrameAnimation?

Answer (score 0):

- Draw parabola with UIBezierPath and convert it to CGPath or Create a CGPath.
- Use CAKeyFrameAnimation to move UIView's position.

Look at the below source code,

Drawing Parabola

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path,NULL,50.0,120.0);

CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path,NULL,50.0,275.0,
                      150.0,275.0,
                      150.0,120.0);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path,NULL,150.0,275.0,
                      250.0,275.0,
                      250.0,120.0);    
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path,NULL,250.0,275.0,
                      350.0,275.0,
                      350.0,120.0);    
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path,NULL,350.0,275.0,
                      450.0,275.0,
                      450.0,120.0);
```

CAKeyFrameAnimation along a path.

```
CAKeyframeAnimation* AniLoc = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"]; // notice key change

// rest is the same
AniLoc.path = thePath;
AniLoc.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
AniLoc.keyTimes= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.3f],
                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f],nil];
AniLoc.duration = 2.0;

CFRelease(thePath);

[self.logo.layer addAnimation:AniLoc forKey:nil];
```

Comment: I am looking to move the view only between certain points on the parabola.. I am looking for a way to specify the start and end points so that i can setup the translation only between those points on the path.. Is there a way to achieve this using  CAKeyFrameAnimation?

Comment: You want to draw parabola but move from a starting point to end point within the parabola. Isn't it?. if you know where to start and end you can construct your CGPath with the points itself.

Comment: So its like creating a small subpath inside the parabola path right?But wouldn't creating such subpaths dynamically inside the parabola path just to move to an end point be complex as ill have to decide on a control point as i am using a bezier path to create the  arc.. Isn't there an easier way to do it? I thought CAKeyFrameAnimation would have some sort of facility that would allow me to specify where i want to exactly move my view between two points within the parabola path

Comment: One more thing i wont be using CGPath to construct paths for two reasons i) i don't want the path to be visible ii)i am not doing this stuff inside drawRect of a subclassed view.. As the path was not required to be seen i resorted to using the BezierPath.. Please Correct me if i am wrong!!

Comment: @Mr.Anonymous: A CGPath doesn't require you to draw it. It's just the CG implementation of a Bézier path. You can use that path to describe motion rather than an outline, as Vignesh's code does.